# I can't save nested json with mongoose and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some issues when saving json data through jquery.

I built 2 projects: an API and another an APP.

In API, I built a service with node.js to provide GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE verbs from a MongoDB database. I have models, controllers, and route files.

**Model: Mytest.js**

```js
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

const mytestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  classname: {type:String},
  color: {type:String},
  owner: {type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users', required:true},
  position: {
    x: {type: Number, required:true},
    y: {type: Number, required:true},
    z: {type: Number, required:true}
  }
});

const mytest = mongoose.model('mytests' , mytestSchema);
module.exports = mytest;
```

**Controller: MyTest.ctrl.js**

```js
let mytest = require('../models/Mytest');

class MyTestCtrl {
  static create = (req,res)=>{
    let myobj = new mytest(req.body);
    myobj.save((err, newmyobj)=>{
      err ? res.status(500).send(`${err.message}`) : res.status(200).send(newmyobj);
    }); 
  };
}
module.exports = MyTestCtrl;
```

**Route: Mytest.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var mytest = require('../src/controller/MyTest.ctrl');
var router = express.Router();

router
  .post('/mytest', mytest.create);

module.exports = router;
```

Now, in my APP, I have the following code:

```js
$("#add_mytest").click(function(){
  let mydata= {
    classname: "This is a test",
    color: "gray",
    owner: "63ee7b392ed75e8905e7feee",
    position: {x:-1.52, y:0.46, z:1.63}
  };

  $.post('http://localhost:3030/mytest', mydata)
    .done(function(newdata){
      console.log(newdata);
    })
    .fail(function(){
      console.log(`there is a error`);
    })
    .always(function(){
      console.log('data sent', mydata);
    });
});
```

According to the code above, I have two situations:

- **Situation 1**: when I send JSON data directly via postman, data are saved in the database.
- **Situation 2**: when I call `#add_mytest`, it shows the following errors on the console:

[image: console-error]

I discover that the problem is position (nested json) because when I delete position in the schema, data are saved.

I just tried with two schemas, but it doesn't work:

```js
const positionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  x:Number,
  y:Number,
  z:Number
});

const mytestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  classname: {type:String},
  color: {type:String},
  owner: {type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users', required:true},
  position: positionSchema
});
```

Therefore, how can I solve that?

Comment: What does "isn't successful" mean? Please see [ask], then revise your post to be more clear.

Comment: Have you tried passing the entire data object with Postman? You've described two different scenarios.

Comment: Hi, guys! I edited my post to improve the understanding.

Comment: After multiple trying, I found a stranger situation. In MyTest.crtl.js, when I changed the code to `res.status(200).send(req.body)`, I received the following data: `position[x]:"1.83", position[y]:"-0.13", position[z]:"-0.63"`, that is, req.body didn't recognize position as an object. So, I wrote a "bad" code to solve it temporarily: `for(let el in req.body) {
  if(el == "position[x]"){
    newdata.position.x = req.body[el]
  }else if(el == "position[y]"){
    newdata.position.y = req.body[el]
  }else if(el == "position[z]"){
    newdata.position.z = req.body[el]
  }
}
`

Comment: That doesn't belong down here. All information must be in your question. Don't put notes about your edits in your question. We can all see the edit history.